Why are there two review tasks for the same edit?
Reviewing suggested edits, I've been shown this suggested edit a few times, each time I submit it, I get redirected to the next task and the site does not save it.
After looking into it in more detail (going to the submitting user's page -> Suggestions), it appears there are two review tasks for the same edit, those being 36216505 (which has two approvals and one rejection, as such it should theoretically be approved already) and 36216506 which I cannot review (as in submitting a verdict fails silently).
This looks like some race condition that one user is able to submit the same edit twice.

That suggested edit illustrates a "race" condition in more than one sense. The consequences of George Floyd's death truly did ripple out to the most unpredictable places.
